# Gmail API setting up service account and reading/sending mails on behalf of user

Tags: java, webserver, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I have a SSL secured jetty web server whose task is to read/send emails on behalf of the user. For reading pub/sub is preferred, instead of pull. Have followed these steps from [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

1. Created a project in console, enabled Gmail api, created service account with google apps domain-wide delegation downloaded both json and p12 private key
2. Created OAuth cliend-id by selecting web application gave it a name and added authorized redirect URI to one of the web server api end point
3. Grant publish right to the topic using console api
4. Created topic in pub-sub and subscribed with an HTTPs endpoint. Manually checked using console API to publish message and received successfully

Now all that left to do is use java client library to utilize service account credentials and talk to gmail api's on behalf of the user (have collected auth & refresh token from the users for the topic)

Steps tried.

1. Using the private key downloaded (p12) tried creating credential and for sample retrieving labels of the mail

   ```
   HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
   JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();    
   String serviceAccount = "service-account@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
   Credential credential = GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)    
   .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
   .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
   .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("/path-to-key-file.p12"))
   .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS))
   .build();
   Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, cred).setApplicationName("web-application-name-created-via-console").build();
   String user = "me"; //Tried direct email id also  
   service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
   ```

Response,

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Bad Request",
    "reason" : "failedPrecondition"
  } ],
  "message" : "Bad Request"
}
```

Note: The coding part is tried in local server and not the one which has SSL. I suppose that shouldn't be an issue as i am having all the necessary key files to access api.

Please, let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: Do you have any way of logging how the final request looks? :) That would be useful. E.g. method, url and headers.

Comment: Did you resolve this? how do you send on behalf of a user?

Comment: Yes using GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault()

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was using the OAuth 2.0 client IDs for my web application to fetch messages from a specific gmail account. And then I realized that consent prompting was not at all required for my application and that's when I stumbled upon the google service accounts that eliminated the consent prompting and storing of the authorization tokens. I did attempt the very same code posted above and hit upon the exact same response posted  `"message" : "Bad Request", "reason" : "failedPrecondition"`.

To resolve the issue added the `.setServiceAccountUser(googleServiceAccountUser)` where  googleServiceAccountUser is set to my google email id (xxx@gmail.com) from which my application was attempting to read messages. In your code snippet provided the call ".setServiceAccountUser()" is missing and adding it may help you resolve the issue.

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {

  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
  .setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
  .setServiceAccountId(googleServiceAccountId)
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(privatekeyFile))
  .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM))
  .setServiceAccountUser(googleServiceAccountUser)
  .build();

  return credential;
}
```